# Can particle object color and alpha be controlled by Particle Age (Blender Internal Render)?

Tags: materials, particles, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

Can particle object color and alpha be changed in Blender Internal Render?

Edit for Clarity 6 months later.

Blender Cycles has this practical feature Particle Info Node.
[image]
Blender Internal appears not to have an equivalent feature.

Blender Internal.  Is it easy to change dynamically, based on strand/particle mapping, halo particle size and opacity. Thus halos of different ages will have different opacity and sizes.   Halo and Object are different choices for particles on the particles pane.

Is it possible to achieve a similar color and transparency control with object particles based on particle age?

**Failed attempts to achieve goal follow**.

I have changed the opacity of a particle halo with a second material with a texture on the emitter.

When I try to change the opacity of a regular particle object, the material selection is grayed in the emitter particle panel.
I added a material and texture using the strand/particle mapping to the particle object.
The particle object was rendered, but the material failed and did not achieve my desired results.

Comment: No.
From various web resources that is my general belief at this moment.
Of course that is ........ if one can ever believe a statement that something is not possible in blender.

Comment: I removed the bit about "not cycles" and "not halo particles" because it's pretty much implied by "can particle **object** color and alpha be changed **in BI**?". That said, if you feel it's *absolutely necessary*, then by all means leave it in. :)

Comment: My emphasis and clarity was intentional.  Most people have been asked more than once in their life ... Please be polite.

Comment: Regarding your question, I'm not sure I fully understand what you want. [Here's a file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31652) with transparent particle objects.. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I have tried to clarify my question.  Please see above.

Answer (score 5):

The way I solved this was to give the particle object (not the emitter) a blend texture, mapped to the coordinates of an empty.

This way, the colour of the particle depends on the distance to the empty.

Example here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/il0aiq8a7gteelw/chimney.blend?dl=0

[image: particle colour]

Comment: That's a good one, but even better would be a screenshot or two of the material setup, so this can be well understood even if you decide to delete that .blend from your Dropbox.

Comment: @nik10110 Good Fortune.   I happened to do a web search today and blender stack appeared.  Good Reminder.   I saw you response just today.  Thank You.  My original question did mention particle age and now the edit emphasizes particle age.  I will keep you technique in my Blender arsenal when next the need arises. I will test you color by distance technique.  Particle Age Color and Transparency is one of the main reasons I use Blender Cycles for simple non photo realistic rendering.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
This link

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/More_Features

This statement

Particle Info node supported in node trees for blender internal and in the viewport thanks to a patch by the Blend4Web team

version 2.76 (sub 0), branch b'master', commit date b'2015-09-23' b'14:02', hash b'e24ea81', b''
build date: b'Thu 09/24/2015', b'09:51 AM'
platform: b'Windows'